# jQuery animate left causes element to jump before moving in Fire Fox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to move one DIV off the screen to the left, and another DIV on screen from the right.  However the first DIV jumps to the right about 100px and then moves left when using FF.

**HTML**

```
<div class="maincontent">
    Goodbye !
</div>  

<div class="maincontent-right">
    Welcome !
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.maincontent {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:blue;
    top: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    left:0px;
    right:0;
}
div.maincontent-right {
    width: 200px;
    top: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    left: 1000px;
    right:0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.maincontent').click(function () {
        $('.maincontent-right').stop().animate({
            left: 0
        }, 1000);
        $('.maincontent').stop().animate({
            left: -1000
        }, 1000);

    })
});
```

[JSFIDDLE link here](http://jsfiddle.net/7yksx0Lz/)

This works fine in Chrome and IE, but in FireFox the element jumps before starting to move...

If it matters for the fix, the `maincontent` and `maincontent-right` elements contain `img` elements in the main project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is seen as you have both Left and Right values set for the two elements.

Here is the updated code that avoids the jumping animation.
[Updated JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/7yksx0Lz/2/)

What essentially I have done is Added another Div wrapper which has the width of 200px and is aligned centrally with Margin as 0px auto. This gives the containing Divs a central position.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.maincontent').click(function () {
        $('.maincontent').stop().animate({
            left: -1000
        }, 1000);
        $('.maincontent-right').stop().animate({
            left: 0
        }, 1000);
    })
});
```

```css
.mainbody {position:relative; width:200px; margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
div.maincontent,div.maincontent-right {
    text-align:left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:blue;
    top: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    left:0px;
}
div.maincontent-right {
    background-color:yellow;
    left: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="mainbody">
        <div class="maincontent-right">Welcome !</div>
        <div class="maincontent">Goodbye !</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this Helps.